# android_alarm_manager_plus is not executed

Tags: android, flutter

I am building an alarm app.
It is a common alarm app, but it is an app that sounds an alarm at a set time.
I am using the android_alarm_manager_plus package to make the alarm go off even when the app is removed from the background.

However, the setAlarm method is not executed even though I want it to always be running.
I checked the logs and debugging and it only executes when I build.

How can I fix this problem?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Alarm.init();
  // await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  AlarmManager alarmManager = AlarmManager();
  alarmManager.setAlarm();

  runApp(const MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = AlarmManager();
    alarmManager.requestPermissions();

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => AlarmPage();
}

class AlarmPage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<AlarmCard> alarms = [];
  AlarmDataService alarmDataService = AlarmDataService();
  AlarmManager alarmManager = AlarmManager();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

    alarmDataService.loadAlarms(alarms, () {
      setState(() {
        print("むむ");
        for (var alarm in alarms) {
          print("アラームID: ${alarm.id}");
          if (alarm.switchValue) {
            print("へ");
            // alarmManager.setupBackgroundAlarm(alarms);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    // alarmManager.startAlarmTimer(context, alarms, () {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

```
class AlarmManager {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  bool isAlarmRinging = false;
  Timer? alarmTimer;
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  AlarmDataService alarmDataService = AlarmDataService();
  Timer? vibrationTimer;
  List<AlarmCard> alarms = [];

  AlarmManager() {
    _initializeNotifications();
  }

  void _initializeNotifications() {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('tokei_clock_icon_2066');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings darwinInitializationSettings =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: androidInitializationSettings,
            iOS: darwinInitializationSettings);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _handleNotificationAction);
  }

  Future<void> _playAlarmSound() async {
    print("よばれ");

    try {
      await audioPlayer.play(AssetSource("ringtone-126505.mp3"));
      audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
      isAlarmRinging = true;
      _showNotification();
      startVibration();
      print("アラーム音が再生しました");
    } catch (e) {
      print("アラーム音の再生中にエラーが発生しました $e");
      isAlarmRinging = false;
    }
  }

  void stopAlarmSound(String alarmId) async {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    isAlarmRinging = false;

    print("アラームを停止しました");
  }

  void startVibration() async {
    vibrationTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      Vibration.vibrate(duration: 500);
    });
  }

  void stopVibration() {
    vibrationTimer?.cancel();
    print("バイブレーションがキャンセルされました");
    Vibration.cancel();
  }

  Future<void> requestPermissions() async {
    print("通知のパーミッションを要求する直後");

    if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermissions(
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          );
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              MacOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.requestPermissions(
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          );
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? androidImplementation =
          flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
      await androidImplementation?.requestPermission();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      icon: "tokei_clock_icon_2066",
      fullScreenIntent: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      ticker: 'ticker',
    );

    const String darwinNotificationCategoryPlain = 'plainCategory';
    const DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      categoryIdentifier: darwinNotificationCategoryPlain,
    );

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: iosNotificationDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'アラーム',
      'ストップ',
      notificationDetails,
      payload: 'stop_action:',
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleNotificationAction(NotificationResponse? payload) async {
    String payloadValue = payload?.payload ?? '';
    print("通知がタップされました。Payload: $payloadValue");

    if (payloadValue.startsWith('stop_action:')) {
      String alarmId = payloadValue.split(':').last;
      stopAlarmSound(alarmId);
      stopVibration();
    }
  }

  void setAlarm() async {
    print("セットですよーー");
    // アラームを設定する処理
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      0,
      backgroundAlarmCallback,
      exact: true,
      wakeup: true,
      // alarmClock: true,
    );
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void backgroundAlarmCallback() async {
    final setAlarms = alarms.where((alarm) => alarm.switchValue).toList();
    final now = DateTime.now();
    print("_backgroundAlarmCallbackですよーー");

    for (var alarm in setAlarms) {
      print("forぶんですよーー");
      print("${setAlarms}");
      if (now.hour == alarm.alarmTime.hour &&
          now.minute == alarm.alarmTime.minute) {
        print("実行されます");
        await _playAlarmSound();
        startVibration();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1))`
could be executed. But this can only be executed when the app is open, so imiganaidesu

I used chatGPT, but it didn't solve the problem.

It has been this way for a long time. I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what is causing this.